# Line break and hyphenation for underlined text

Tags: hyphenation, ulem, underline

I am struggling with a problem that occurs using `\underline`. From other posts I heard that there is no possiblity for linebreaks using this command. However, I tried using the `ulem` package. In fact, line breaks are possible but hyphenation is not. So, I face another problem. I have a continuous text with some underlined parts of a sentence which need line breaks as well as hyphenation.

How am I supposed to solve this?

My code:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item There is an item:
    \begin{itemize}

        %using \underline
        \item[] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                 \underline{thereIsAReallyLongWord in a senctence} 
                aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.


        %using \uline
        \item[] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                \uline{thereIsAReallyLongWord in a senctence} 
                aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a complete MWE from your code. And the long word you are mentioning probably would not break as it is not a real word. If I set the hyphenation using `\-` at the appropriate positions line breaking works.

Comment: do you really have to use underlining (it is a typewriter convention rather rarely used in typeset material)  ulem should work OK if you use hyphenatable text but  if at all possible I would use a font change such as italic instead.

Answer (score 6):

It works with `soul`, but, please, don't use underlining.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item There is an item:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
%          elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
          \ul{thereIsAReallyLongWord in a sentence}
          aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]